# Reply mechanism and Tx management in Oracle BPEL

Tags: web-services, oracle, soa, bpel, business-process-management

I am getting request timed out exception when invoking an asynchronous BPEL service from a synchrnous BPEL service.

Am in the learning stage and created an async bpel with a wait of only 5 seconds and invoked it using a synchronous BPEL but still am getting a timedout error
The invoked async process has completed after waiting for 5 seconfs but even then the sync process is waiting for response

While invoking the the same asynchronous service using another async bpel service its working fine.

why am getting this error while a async bpel service is invoked using a sync service

I tried to change the sync process transaction property to 'requriesNew' by a wild guess

### Async Process

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<!--
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Oracle JDeveloper BPEL Designer 

  Created: Wed Jan 30 16:13:48 IST 2013
  Author:  loganvm
  Type: BPEL 1.1 Process
  Purpose: Asynchronous BPEL Process
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-->
<process name="TestAsync"
         targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/BankInterestRate/TestAsyncproject/TestAsync"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
         xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/BankInterestRate/TestAsyncproject/TestAsync"
         xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
         xmlns:bpelx="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"
         xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
         xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
         xmlns:bpel2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
         xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
         xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
         xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
         xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
         xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
         xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
         xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap">

    <!-- 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        PARTNERLINKS                                                      
        List of services participating in this BPEL process               
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    --> 
    <partnerLinks>
        <!-- 
      The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. It is 
      used for callback. The location and correlation information associated
      with the client role are automatically set using WS-Addressing.
    -->
        <partnerLink name="testasync_client" partnerLinkType="client:TestAsync" myRole="TestAsyncProvider" partnerRole="TestAsyncRequester"/>
    </partnerLinks>

    <!-- 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        VARIABLES                                                        
        List of messages and XML documents used within this BPEL process 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    -->
    <variables>
        <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
        <variable name="inputVariable" messageType="client:TestAsyncRequestMessage"/>

        <!-- Reference to the message that will be sent back to the requester during callback -->
        <variable name="outputVariable" messageType="client:TestAsyncResponseMessage"/>
        <variable messageType="bpelx:bindingFault" name="FaultVar"/>
        <variable messageType="bpelx:remoteFault" name="FaultVar_1"/>
    </variables>
    <faultHandlers>
        <catch faultName="bpelx:bindingFault" faultVariable="FaultVar"/>
    </faultHandlers>
    <!-- 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       ORCHESTRATION LOGIC                                               
       Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the    
       services integrated within this business process                  
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    -->
    <sequence name="main">
        <!-- Receive input from requestor. (Note: This maps to operation defined in TestAsync.wsdl) -->
        <receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="testasync_client" portType="client:TestAsync" operation="process" variable="inputVariable" createInstance="yes"
                 bpelx:conversationId="1"/>
        <assign name="assign_hello">
            <bpelx:append>
                <bpelx:from expression="concat(bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload','/client:process/client:input'),' Hello')"/>
                <bpelx:to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                          query="/client:processResponse/client:result"/>
            </bpelx:append>
        </assign>
        <wait name="Wait1" for="'PT5S'"/>
        <!-- 
          Asynchronous callback to the requester. (Note: the callback location and correlation id is transparently handled using WS-addressing.)
        -->
        <invoke name="callbackClient" partnerLink="testasync_client" portType="client:TestAsyncCallback" operation="processResponse" inputVariable="outputVariable"
                bpelx:invokeAsDetail="no" bpelx:conversationId="1"/>
    </sequence>
</process>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the two processes? I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but an asynchronous operation doesn't reply anything (as it is asynchronous).

Comment: I don't know about the constructs in the bpelx namespace, but does your synchronous process have a second receive, one that matches the invoke in the asynchronous process, in between the sychronous receive-reply pair? It might help if you paste the code of your synchronous process as well.

Comment: Could you also post the source of the Synchronous process, I can only see the async process.

Answer (score 0):

**To debug** this problem:

- **enabled audit**, run in a **development mode** and then **run** the synchronous process **from the test console**. This will show you the process flow, invocations and the place where the synchronous process is waiting.

Answer (score 0):

try adding any of these combinations in the transaction properties.

```
bpel.config.transaction=required
bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy=async.persist
```

If above pair is no help... try just adding below and comment out bpel.config.transaction property

```
bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy=async.persist
```